# How to add buttons to embed pages discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, discord-buttons

I've been trying to add buttons to my slash command to make embed pages. All the info I've been able to find has either just been on buttons (not buttons + slash commands) or needs to be done within the index file and not done with a command handler. I've tried adding an await to the interaction.reply but it sends an error that it needs to be within an async function. I'm not entirely sure how async/await works so I couldn't work much more on that if that would be the proper way to solve my issue. How would I collect the button interaction within a command handled file to edit the embeds on button click? [This is the guide I used to create the initial command handler](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-handling.html).
Here's my current info.js file.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const info = require("./info.json");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("cinfo")
    .setDescription("Shows AniGame card info")
    .addStringOption(option =>
      option
        .setName("name")
        .setDescription("Enter the name of a card")
        .setRequired(false)
    ),
  async execute(interaction) {
    const msg = interaction.options.getString("name").toLowerCase();

    function cinfo(
      name,
      info,
      stats,
      talent,
      image,
      sr1,
      sr2,
      sr3,
      srt,
      ur1,
      ur2,
      ur3,
      urt
    ) {
      const base = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(name)
        .setColor(0xffd1dc)
        .setDescription(info)
        .addField("__Card Stats__", stats)
        .addField("Talent", talent)
        .setImage(image);

      const sr = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(name + " | Level 50")
        .setColor(0xffd1dc)
        .addField("__SR Evo 1__", sr1, true)
        .addField("__SR Evo 2__", sr2, true)
        .addField("__SR Evo 3__", sr3, true)
        .addField("Talent", srt)
        .setImage(image);

      const ur = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(name + " | Level 60")
        .setColor(0xffd1dc)
        .addField("__UR Evo 1__", ur1, true)
        .addField("__UR Evo 2__", ur2, true)
        .addField("__UR Evo 3__", ur3, true)
        .addField("Talent", urt)
        .setImage(image);

      const row = new Discord.MessageActionRow().addComponents(
        new Discord.MessageButton()
          .setCustomId("backward")
          .setStyle("PRIMARY")
          .setEmoji("⬅️"),

        new Discord.MessageButton()
          .setCustomId("forward")
          .setStyle("PRIMARY")
          .setEmoji("➡️"),

        new Discord.MessageButton()
          .setCustomId("delete")
          .setStyle("DANGER")
          .setEmoji("️")
      );

      const pages = [base, sr, ur];

      interaction.reply({ embeds: [base], components: [row] });
      // await interaction.editReply()
        
    }
    
    // location 1
    if (
      msg === "itaru hashida" ||
      msg === "itaru" ||
      msg === "hashida"
    ) {
      cinfo(
        info.Itaru_Hashida[0],
        info.Itaru_Hashida[1],
        info.Itaru_Hashida[2],
        info.Itaru_Hashida[3],
        info.Itaru_Hashida[4],
        info.Itaru_Hashida[5],
        info.Itaru_Hashida[6],
        info.Itaru_Hashida[7],
        info.Itaru_Hashida[8],
        info.Itaru_Hashida[9],
        info.Itaru_Hashida[10],
        info.Itaru_Hashida[11],
        info.Itaru_Hashida[12]
      );
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions I found for your question:

## Solution 1: Package

I have created a [package called `discord.js-util`](https://npm.im/discord.js-util) that does various things like [create embed pages](https://npm.im/discord.js-util#pages). You could install it **or** just copy the source code [here](https://github.com/Pepperbot-Development/Discord-Util/blob/main/classes/pages.js).

## Solution 2: Create your own

As [@Qreepex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15037063/qreepex) said you can create your own by using a [`interactionCollector`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/InteractionCollector) and then using the [`customId`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=customId) to check if it should to back or forward.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to do this.

1. You can use the [interactionCreate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-interactionCreate) event. Whenever the event is emitted, you can use [`<interaction>.isButton()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=isButton) to check if the interaction is from a button. If so, you can edit the [`<interaction>.message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=message) with the [`<interaction>.message.edit`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=edit) method.
2. You can also use an [InteractionCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/InteractionCollector) ([How to use](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=createMessageComponentCollector) | [Example](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#responding-to-buttons)).

Comment: My issue is still the same, I'm not sure how to do that within a command handler. The only things I've seen/read about have used the interactionCreate event solely within the index.js file.